# Live server in Vs code not updating in real time

Tags: visual-studio-code

Liver server doesn't updates in real time. It only updates if i stop live server and open it again. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had this issue, but found this GitHub issue [github-issue](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/452). The main key points there were to set the meta charset = "UTF-8" in the head of the HTML and to make sure autosave is enabled in the VS-Code settings. I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, great to hear :)